# How to fetch using axios when the api comes from a state via reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

I would like to fetch a an api from the state which was returned from the reducer.
This is my container: PokeDetailApi.js

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import axios from "axios";

class PokeDetailApi extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            pokedetails:""
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get({this.props.pokemon.url}).then( (obj) => {
            this.setState({
                pokedetails: obj.data.results
            });
        });
    }

    render(){
        if(!this.props.pokemon){
            return (
                <div>
                    <h1>Please select a pokemon.</h1>
                </div>
            )
        }

        // const url = this.props.pokemon.url;
        const urlapi = this.state.pokedetails;

        console.log(url);
        console.log(urlapi);

        return(
            <div>
                <p>{this.props.pokemon.name}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        pokemon: state.selected_pokemon
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PokeDetailApi);
```

{this.props.pokemon.url} returns a url of a specific pokemon. I want to display all the details of that pokemon using that url which is found here: https://pokeapi.co/

This is the returned object from the reducer:

```
{
    name:"bulbasaur"
    url:"http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/"
}
```

What is the correct way of accessing the objects from an api from a reducer using axios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about reducers, but calling fetch directly in your component.. you should be calling an action which does the fetching.

Anyway aside from this you can perform another fetch in your .then using the result of the first fetch (pokedetails), not in your render:

```
axios.get(this.props.pokemon.url)
  .then(res => res.data.results)
  .then(axios.get) // fetch on pokedetails
  .then(console.log) // console.log result, here you could setState results
```

Comment: I'll be trying that. It is bad practice to do api calls in the component? I'll take note of that.

Comment: The idea of redux is to remove those "side-effects" to actions, so you would normally pass an action to the component and call that in componentDidMount instead - see https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk for more details

Comment: However calling fetch directly in your component is not a terrible thing to do or anything, and is actually the most productive and fastest way to get things done. This adds another level of abstraction, which coders love, but isn't necessary unless you want to be very "purist" and remove such logic from your components

Comment: Do you need to return a promise on the action? or just do something like axios.get(pokemon.url); inside the function?

Comment: yep if you're using redux-thunk it expects you to return a promise (well just a function). The idea is that you can dispatch multiple actions in there, for example a starting, success and failed actions - so you can do loading spinners and show errors messages if it fails

Comment: for example - https://github.com/DominicTobias/universal-react/blob/master/app/actions/users.js

Comment: I have not tried redux-thunk yet. I will try that in the near future. Thanks.